# extra space in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I seem to be getting space between the game_button and then the next class

```
<div class="blurb">
    <div class="game_box">
        <img src="imgs/pack.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="game_text">
        <img src="imgs/game_text.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="game_button">
        <a target="_parent" href="http://yourshapecenter.com/"><img border="0" src="imgs/button.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
```

css-

```
 .blurb{

    padding-top:42px;
    margin-left:24px;
    width:468px;
}
.game_box{
    float:left;
}

.game_text{
    float:right;
}
.game_button{

    padding-top:13px;
    clear:both;
    display: block;

}
.bottom{
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-left:24px;
    height:161px;

}
```

if you look at the image below you can see the button is outside of the box- it should be in the box with a few pixels spare below it

[image: too much space]

Comment: Could you explain which box has which class?

Comment: box backgroud is fixed height or not?

Comment: you can view the tab here- http://0like.com/yourshape/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking the img tags out and instead setting them as background images to the divs? And also maybe setting all the other margins and padding to 0? As in the ones that have not already been set.